# Haskell (n+1) in pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I was doing the [99 Problems in Haskell](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/) when I encountered a [solution](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/19) to [Problem 19](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/11_to_20#Problem_19) that I did not fully understand.

The task is to write a rotate function that works like this

```
*Main> rotate ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'] 3
"defghabc"

*Main> rotate ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'] (-2)
"ghabcdef"
```

One provided solution is

```
rotate [] _ = []
rotate l 0 = l
rotate (x:xs) (n+1) = rotate (xs ++ [x]) n
rotate l n = rotate l (length l + n)
```

I don't understand how the pattern matching can ever reach the fourth line. It seems to have to do with the `(n+1)` so that when `n` is negative the third line does not match and therefore the fourth is taken. If that is the case why does the notation `(n+1)` work that way resp. isn't that arbitrary or is that a convention (in mathematics?) that I'm not aware of?

Because the way I understand it is that rotate is called recursively in the third line with the argument `n` reduced by one. So I would think that

```
rotate [] _ = []
rotate l 0 = l
rotate (x:xs) n = rotate (xs ++ [x]) (n-1)
rotate l n = rotate l (length l + n)
```

is equivalent. However, it is not. This definition gives the following warning

```
Warning: Pattern match(es) are overlapped
         In the definition of `rotate': rotate l n = ...
```

whereas the former definition compiles just fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a specific case of what is called "n+k patterns", which is generally disliked, and [<s>will be</s> has been removed from the language](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RemoveNPlusK). See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching#n.2Bk_patterns) for more information.

[Here](http://sites.google.com/site/haskell/notes/nkpatterns) is a good note on n+k patterns, which quotes the following from the Haskell 98 Report (emphasis mine):

> Matching an n+k pattern (where n is a
>   variable and k is a positive integer
>   literal) against a value v **succeeds if
>   x >= k**, resulting in the binding of n
>   to x - k, and fails otherwise. Again,
>   the functions >= and - are overloaded,
>   depending on the type of the pattern.
>   The match diverges if the comparison
>   diverges.
>
> The interpretation of the literal k is
>   the same as in numeric literal
>   patterns, except that only integer
>   literals are allowed.

So the `n+1` is only matched if `n` is at least 1, as you suspected. Your alternative code removes this restriction, resulting in overlapping pattern matches.

Comment: "It's a specific case of what is called "n+k patterns", which is generally disliked". I think the better solution could have been introducing a type for natural numbers, which can be used to express *size*, and define the *n+1* pattern on naturals. Lacking this type in Haskell and most languages, like C/C++, we see the pains of defining `unsigned int`, `size_t` (which is really naturals under the hood) and associated issues of comparison between signed and unsigne type etc. With the naturals, we can do case analysis on the size of structures, which is quite fundamental, and easy in Haskell.